# Where are the release notes for Microsoft nuget packages?

Tags: nuget-package, release-management

Does Microsoft publish release notes for individual nuget packages?

I noticed a few nuget packages with a 'dot' release (which leads me to believe some bugs were resolved) but I can't find information about what exactly was fixed in these dot releases.

Here are a few examples, picked at random, of packages released by Microsoft:

- [System.Net.Http version 4.3.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/)
- [System.Reflection.Metadata version 1.4.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Metadata/)
- [System.Collections.Immutable version 1.3.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/)
- [Microsoft.Data.OData version 5.8.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/)
- [Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Core 2.2.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/)

The description for most of these packages says that release notes are available at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799421 but that's a link to the release notes for .NET Core 1.1.0 Preview 1 released 10/24/2016, nothing specific to the packages.

An example of a Microsoft nuget package that publishes very clear release notes for each version is [Windows Azure Storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/changelog.txt).

Comment: Microsoft could definitely be more forthcoming here.  They seemed to have changed their deployment strategy for .NET Core.  In the past, I could rely on a single, periodic update to the entire .NET Framework.  Now it seems that major framework namespaces are individually deployed through Nuget.  My current project suddenly has multiple framework packages asking to be updated, and I have no idea what the changes are or if they affect me.

Comment: Yes, trying to find release notes for NuGet updates is an annoyingly impossible task.  I guess we can all start adding and upvoting issues for each project on github or wherever the issue tracking system lives, like this one: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/issues/17